# iPhone Simulator is running the wrong code

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I cannot get the iPhone Simulator to run the current code. Instead it runs an old build. Does anyone know why?
The simulation starts and stops as usual, but somehow Xcode and Simulator have lost their connection. The Simulator ignores any changes in the code and Xcode ignores any breakpoints.
I have:

- Deleted the app in the Simulator.
- Reset content and settings in the Simulator.
- Cleaned the project in Xcode.
- Removed the project from Organizer.
- Restarted Xcode and computer.

System info:

- Xcode 6.0.1
- iOS Simulator 8.0
- OS X 10.10

If someone can tell me why this is happening I would be very thankful! 
By the way, I can run the code on a device without problems.

Comment: May be you should try it by deleting the derived data..

Comment: Try to reset you're simulator.At me work.

Comment: Maybe something here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323819/is-there-a-quicker-better-way-to-clear-the-iphone-simulator-cache-than-deletin

Comment: @pankajwadhwa Tried it, but it didn't work. I went to Xcode/Preferences…/Locations, clicked the little white arrow to show Derived Data in Finder, and deleted its content.

Comment: are you also using Xcode 5 at the same time? @turingtested

Comment: is Xcode5 even ON the machine?

Comment: @PaulCezanne NO. Not in Application folder and not anywhere else that I can find.

Comment: Drat, it was an idea. I guess you haven't solved this yet. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I upgraded to Xcode 6.1 AND downloaded a new iOS 7.1 Simulator (available at Xcode/Preferences/Downloads) then it just started to work again. So, to upgrade or simply reinstall Xcode seems to solve this problem.

**EDIT:**
I recently got the same problem again, and I fixed it this time by going to Project Navigator/Targets/Build Settings/Build Locations. Changed the text of Build Products Path to something random, and changed it back again.

Sometimes, if you move your project folder around, it seems that Xcode loses track of its build folder. By doing this Xcode restore its build-path. So try this method first.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset content and settings of the simulator. Like on the image:

[image]

Clean and rebuild the project also may help.

Comment: Thats a good answer in most of the cases. But it didn't work for me, as you can see in the question.