# How to delete ios simulator safari cache

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, ios-simulator, browser-cache

I'm trying to test a website on the iphone simulator, I made some javascript changes and my javascript files are being loaded from cache.

I see the old version files with safari web inspector, resources tab (on simulator window), also the network calls have status 304.
I already disabled cache on macos Safari.
I already tried deleting the safari cache on the simulator settings.
Safari outside the emulator is loading the new files correctly (I emptied/disabled the cache).

I'm using Simulator (10.0 SimulatorAPP-745.10 with iOS 10.3) from XCode on Sierra

How do I delete or disable the simulator cache?

Comment: Simulator > Hardware > "Erase all Content and Settings".  Erases all settings and restarts simulator, the only way I found.  I wasn't able to do it from an attached safari.

Answer (score 53):

For anyone coming in in 2018 : if you have a Safari attached, click on Network tab, then on the top line, "Ignore cache resources" icon ( just next to "Export" button ).

[image]

Seems to do the trick.

Comment: where can this be found? ios safari doesnt have dev tools unlike mac osx version

Answer (score 0):

2024: Device/Erase all content and settings

[Image showing the relevant drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW01D.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35822119)