# +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'myModel' in this model in core data - what's missing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm now building up Core Data based iOS application and when I tried to insert new managed object by executing `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEintityForName:@"myModel" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];` within `AppDelegate.m`, I got the error described on the title.

Here's my `AppDelegate.h` file:

```
#import 

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder 

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

// maybe required?
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end
```

And here's my `AppDelegate.m` file (only displaying the relevant part):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "MyModel.h"
#import "listViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //managed object context settings
    UITabBarController *tabbarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[tabbarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    listViewController *listcontroller = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    listcontroller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    NSLog(@"%@", _persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel);


    MyModel *newMyModel = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyModel" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

    return YES;
}
```

in this application, I want to use tabbar controller as root view controller and when the app starts, I want to navigation controller as the tabbar controller's root view controller, and use tableview controller as the navigation controller's root view controller. And in the table view controller, I want to use Core Data functionality to display a lot of entities to users.

If I used breakpoint at the exact point of the `NSLog()` output, it didn't return any errors. And when I moved one line forward to output the log message, the following output returns:

```
() isEditable 0, entities {
}, fetch request templates {
}
```

which means I don't have entities for some reasons.

So why are there no entities in this situation? From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100302/coredata-error-entityforname-could-not-locate-an-nsmanagedobjectmodel-for-ent) here over SO, I don't misspelled my entity name. Also, my objectModelContext is not set to nil. So did I set the wrong managed object? Am I doing something wrong in the first three lines in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method?

Or is there something that is causing the issue here? Or what am I missing?

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5 and I don't have any managed objects in my entity - after all, the error happened when I tried to instantiate those managed objects.

Thanks.

Comment: You could post your code that creates your `ManagedObjectModel`?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean. Is `ManagedObjectModel` created automatically by writing `@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
` in header and `@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
` in implementation file, right?

Comment: No - so those lines just *declare* the `ManagedObjectModel` property. You need code to initialize / create the actual model. By default, Xcode places this into a method in your AppDelegate.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't know how to initialize `ManagedObjectModel`. The method `-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext` within `AppDelegate.m` is called when I start the app, right? Then, you're right, that editing its method enables my app to work now. I actually copied and pasted its code from another template, because as I said, I have to use tabbar controller as root (not having Core Data at default) and have not changed its model name to new one.

Comment: And could you tell me one more thing then - In the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`method, the `managedObjectContext` method isn't called. So then where and when is it called in the app?

Comment: Posted as part of my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, it looks like you probably needed to check how your `ManagedObjectModel` was being initialized.

I'd personally recommend avoiding placing Core Data code directly in your app delegate - I don't think Apple's templates do this very well. Check out [this blog post](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/09/07/the-core-data-stack/) as a great example of the minimal amount of code that's required to set up a Core Data stack, as well as a brief explanation of what each part does.

Regarding your extra comment question - the `managedObjectContext` method you have is called whenever your `managedObjectContext` property is accessed. So, when you do:

```
listcontroller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

This calls the `managedObjectContext` method on `self`, which (if I remember correctly) will initialize your context.